# deleting first line when reading csv in Java

Tags: java, arrays, csv, bufferedreader

I've read similar topics but havent found any which use this method of reading so I couldn't fix it.

How can I skip the first line when reading using the following method?
BTW, I have trouble with the second read, after the line with:

```
File file = new File("attendance.csv");
```

Code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ClassAttendance {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

            int rowCount = 0;
            int colCount = 0;

        Scanner rc = new Scanner(new File("attendance.csv"));
        while (rc.hasNextLine()) {
            rowCount++;
            rc.nextLine();
        }
        rc.close();

    File file = new File("attendance.csv");
    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(file.toPath(), 
            StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    double sum = 0;
    double avg;
        for(int n=1; n<3; ++n){
            for (String line : lines) {
        String[] array = line.split(",");
        System.out.println(array[n]);

        sum = sum + Double.parseDouble(array[n]);
    }   
        avg = sum/rowCount;
        System.out.print("Week ");
        System.out.print(n);
        System.out.print("Average = ");
        System.out.print(avg);
        System.out.println();
    }

}
}
```

So far I tried putting:

```
List<String> headerLine = Files.readLine(file.toPath());
```

above the "readAllLines" line but it didn't work for me

Comment: The problem is in the next part, after "File file = new File("attendance.csv");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to replace the following lines:

```
for (String line : lines) {
    String[] array = line.split(",");
...
```

To these:

```
for (int i=1; i<lines.size(); i++) {
    String[] array = lines.get(i).split(",");
...
```

In this way we can skip reading the first line (as we initialize `i=1` instead of "normal" `i=0`).

Comment: That worked beautifully, I was having trouble for ages with this, thanks so much!

Comment: @Win Thanks a lot :-)